# How do I stop propagation of an Angular (click) event using the event trigger from a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I'm trying to include an icon in the date input box for the bootstrap datepicker. I want the icon to serve as a button that opens and closes the date picker. When I click the icon to close the datepicker immediately a "hide" event is triggered and the datepicker is closed. I want to stop the event propagation right there so that the Angular (click) event will not reopen the datepicker right after it was closed. I would really appreciate some help, thank you!

**The Element:**

```
<div class="input-group date dp-textbox">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker dp-input" />
    <i class="icon-appointment dp-icon" role="button" aria-label="Open Datepicker" (click)="openDp()"></i>
</div>
```

**The Hide Event:**

```
$(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.datepicker').datepicker().on('hide', (e) => {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      console.log("this should be stopping propagation");
    });
```

**The Click Event:**

```
openDp() {
    console.log("show this funciton");
    $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.datepicker').datepicker('show');
  }
```

Comment: It’s better to use Angular’s click handlers/events instead of searching the DOM with jQuery. Angular takes care of that for you.

Comment: @Kokodoko I would prefer to use Angular's click handlers/events, but because of some incompatibility issues I'm stuck using the bootstrap jQuery datepicker instead of the ngbDatepicker. Is it possible to handle the bootstrap datepicker's on hide event purely with Angular? Thanks!